# Scrapy repeated JSON outputs from nested parsing methods

Tags: python, json, parsing, scrapy, request

I am trying to scrape data from Walmart.ca/grocery store, to obtain the following output model specified in the item class. For this, I have implemented three nested parse methods to retrieve:

1. the list of products per page (in case next button exists)
2. relevant information available from HTML body (couldn't directly related JSON files through this)
3. dealing with JSON requests for stock availability

I have managed to retrieve the basic information that is available on the page itself, however, requesting the JSON files for stock availability has been a little challenging, because the output sees repeated for the last level of the parsing methods.

Could you please review my code lines and advise some solutions to this?

```
import scrapy
import json
import re
from pprint import pprint
from product_scraping.items import Product


class CaWalmartBot(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'walmart'
    allowed_domains = ['walmart.ca']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.walmart.ca/en/grocery/fruits-vegetables/fruits/N-3852'
    ]
    stores = {'3106': ['43.656422', '-79.435567'], '3124': ['48.412997', '-89.239717']}

    def parse(self, response):
        for url in response.css('.product-link::attr(href)').getall():
            yield response.follow(url, callback=self.parse_first_level)
        next_page = response.css('#loadmore::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_first_level(self, response):
        # """To Scrape: category, package"""
        data_1 = json.loads(response.xpath("/html/body/script[1]/text()").get()[27::][:-1])
        # """To Scrape: price, description, sku, image_url, store, name, brand"""
        data_2 = json.loads(response.css('.evlleax2 > script:nth-child(1)::text').get())
        url_link = response.xpath('/html/head/link[40]/@href').get()

        sku = data_2['sku']
        upc = data_1['entities']['skus'][sku]['upc']
        # url_json = 'https://www.walmart.ca/api/product-page/find-in-store?' \
        #            'latitude={}&longitude={}&lang=en&upc=' + upc[0]
        url_json = 'https://www.walmart.ca/api/product-page/find-in-store?' \
                   'latitude=48.412997&longitude=-89.239717&lang=en&upc=' + upc[0]

        args = {'data_1': data_1, 'data_2': data_2, 'url': url_link}

        yield scrapy.http.Request(url_json, callback=self.parse_second_level,
                              meta=args, dont_filter=True)

    def parse_second_level(self, response):
        item = Product()

        data_json = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        pprint(data_json)
        data_1 = response.meta.get('data_1')
        data_2 = response.meta.get('data_2')
        url = response.meta.get('url')

        sku = data_2['sku']
        product_type = data_1['entities']['skus'][sku]['facets'][0]['value']
        category_1 = data_1['entities']['skus'][sku]['categories'][0]['hierarchy'][0]['displayName']['en']
        category_2 = data_1['entities']['skus'][sku]['categories'][0]['hierarchy'][1]['displayName']['en']
        category_3 = data_1['entities']['skus'][sku]['categories'][0]['hierarchy'][2]['displayName']['en']
        category = ' | '.join([category_3, category_2, category_1, product_type])
        upc = data_1['entities']['skus'][sku]['upc']
        package = data_1['entities']['skus'][sku]['description']
        description = data_2['description']
        name = data_2['name']
        brand = data_2['brand']['name']
        image_url = data_2['image']

        item['barcodes'] = upc
        item['store'] = re.findall(r'\.[\w]+\.', url)[0].replace('.', '').capitalize()
        item['category'] = category
        item['package'] = package
        item['url'] = url
        item['brand'] = brand
        item['image_url'] = image_url
        item['description'] = description.replace('<br>', '')
        item['sku'] = sku
        item['name'] = name

        branch = data_json['info'][0]['id']
        stock = data_json['info'][0]['availableToSellQty']
        price = data_json['info'][0]['sellPrice']

        item['branch'] = branch
        item['stock'] = stock
        item['price'] = price

        return item
```

The item class is:

```
import scrapy


class Product(scrapy.Item):
    store = scrapy.Field()
    barcodes = scrapy.Field()
    sku = scrapy.Field()
    brand = scrapy.Field()
    name = scrapy.Field()
    description = scrapy.Field()
    package = scrapy.Field()
    image_url = scrapy.Field()
    product = scrapy.Field()
    category = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
    branch = scrapy.Field()
    stock = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()

    pass
```

Outputs for stock, price and branch are the same for every item I scraped, any toughts on this?
Thanks!

Comment: A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may get you more feedback, and possibly allow you to figure out the issue yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In your `parse_first_level` method when yielding the request with your callback to `parse_second_level` you specified `dont_filter=True`. That disables Scrapys built in duplication filter. If you do this instead `yield scrapy.http.Request(url_json, callback=self.parse_second_level, meta=args)` you shouldn't get duplicates.

Comment: Patrick, I tried this before with no success. For some reason, the response of that request yields the same json from the first scraped item in parse_first_level. As if values from the following request were ignored.